# Traverse a tree from node to root keeping track of path

Tags: c, memory-management, tree, traversal

I'm building a program to mock a file system. It has virtual files and directories representad as nodes in a tree.
I want to implement a version of "pwd" command as a function on that tree.
given the current directory - I need to traverse up the tree until the root and keep track of the full path;

I've tried some things but I'm not dealing well with the memory allocation.
I will appriciate any help.
Thanks!

Here is the tree struct and my try -

```
typedef struct Node {
    char* nameOfTheFile;
    struct Node* firstChild;
    struct Node* nextSibling;
    struct Node* parent;
    int isFile;
} NODE;

NODE* root;
NODE* currentLocation; 

char* prepend(char* path, const char* toAdd, int lastWordBeforeRoot)
{

    char *newPath = (char*)malloc(strlen(path) + 3 + strlen(toAdd));
    strcat(newPath, path);

    if(!lastWordBeforeRoot && strcmp(toAdd, "/") != 0){
        strcat(newPath,"/");
    }
    strcat(newPath,toAdd);
    free(path);
    strcat(newPath, "\0");

    return newPath;
}

void pwd() {

    NODE* currentFolder = currentLocation;
    char* path = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

    while (currentFolder != NULL) {

        if (currentFolder->parent != NULL && strcmp(currentFolder->parent->nameOfTheFile, "/") == 0) 
        {

            path = prepend(path, currentFolder->nameOfTheFile, 1);
        }
        else 
        {
            path = prepend(path, currentFolder->nameOfTheFile, 0);
        }

        currentFolder = currentFolder->parent;

    }
    printf("%s \n", path);
}
```

Comment: _"..I'm not dealing well with the memory allocation"_: this is not a problem description. Please read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]. Then [edit]  your question and clarify. The problem may be in the code you didn't show.

Comment: `path = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));` This allocates 1 byte to `path`. You need to specify the maximum size e.g. `path = malloc(256 * sizeof(char))`

Comment: Also in `pwd()` : even if the memory allocatation here was correct:`char* path = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char))` (see also previous comment), you dont put anything into the `path` buffer but you pass it to `prepend`, and there you read from the uninitialized `path` buffer. But anyway there may be more problems in the code you didn't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many `malloc` calls in your program. Also `strcat(newPath, "\0");` is redundant. `strcat` will automatically add the trailing NULL character.

A simplified version is given below which will support path lengths upto 256 bytes and indicate error for longer paths.

```
char* prepend(char* path, const char* toAdd, int lastWordBeforeRoot)
{
    if (strlen(path) + strlen(add) + 3 > 256)
    {
        // handle error
        return(path);
    }
    if(!lastWordBeforeRoot && strcmp(toAdd, "/") != 0)
    {
        strcat(path,"/");
    }
    strcat(path,toAdd);
    return (path);
}

void pwd() 
{
    NODE* currentFolder = currentLocation;
    char* path = (char*)malloc(256 * sizeof(char));

    while (currentFolder != NULL) 
    {
        if (currentFolder->parent != NULL && strcmp(currentFolder->parent->nameOfTheFile, "/") == 0) 
        {
            path = prepend(path, currentFolder->nameOfTheFile, 1);
        }
        else 
        {
            path = prepend(path, currentFolder->nameOfTheFile, 0);
        }
        currentFolder = currentFolder->parent;
    }
    printf("%s \n", path);
    free(path);
}
```